# Disable Klocwork Continuous Analysis by default

Tags: klocwork

How do we disable the "Continuous Analysis" option in Klocwork by default?

I know how to disable it for the Eclipse plugin and for .sln files, which works fine, but this is an additional step that must be performed each time a user creates an .sln file or eclipse work space.  And they end up checking out a license to do this (unless they modify the local.properties file directly).

Is there a way to set this to default to off globally, without modifying each MS Visual Studio / Eclipse workspace individually ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to switch off CA globally in the current version. For better / more immediate feedback, you can use the community forums at http://developer.klocwork.com.